# How to create $var from $str with regexp using Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have

```
$str = "dfsdfsdfsd fdsdfs ifdasda id=322dasd-ewwedasda"
```

and wrote a regex

```
\id\=\w.+
```

I need to get the result

```
$string = "id=322dasd-ewwedasda"
```

Comment: You aren't trying to parse XML with regular expressions, are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $str = 'dfsdfsdfsd fdsdfs ifdasda id=322dasd-ewwedasda';
my ($string) = $str =~ /\b(id=\w.+)/;
```

`$string` will be undef if there's no match. You can also die if there's no match using the following:

```
my ($string) = $str =~ /\b(id=\w.+)/
    or die("No match!");
```

Though `\w.+` is a very strange pattern to use.  Perhaps you wanted `\w+`?

Answer (score 1):

That's not exactly hard to do. Did you try anything at all?

Just to get this thing out of the way

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $str = "dfsdfsdfsd fdsdfs ifdasda id=322dasd-ewwedasda";

($str) = $str =~ /\b(id=\S+)/;
say $str;
```

### output

```
id=322dasd-ewwedasda
```